# How to share file with data-test-id attributes between frontend and automation testing projects/repos

Tags: git, automation, frontend, repository, e2e-testing

I have front-end and end-to-end projects in separate repositories. And I'm wondering how to organize the work with data-test-id attributes that are used in the e2e project. I would like to stare them in some file instead of copy and pasting them from front-end to e2e project. How can I easily share a read/write constant JSON file?

This should be managed by git to make sure that the frontend, constants, and e2e tests use the same version. But I would not like to create an external repository for the file if possible.

Selenium Webdriver, React, Gitlab

I have tried to use submodules but seems like it's not helpful in this case

Comment: Are there any specific reasons for not including the e2e tests directly in the front-end project? I would strongly recommend doing that.

Comment: Also have you looked into using [Cypress instead of selenium](https://automatenow.io/cypress-vs-selenium/)? Cypress test are just so much more pleasant to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a npm package and include it as a dependency in both projects. You can use npm workspaces https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces. Crate directory shared in one project. Add packages.json in the root of your  project:

```
 {
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "shared"
  ]
}
```

You should be able to install it with: `npm install ../shared`